# How to send HTTP requests as quickly as possible in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-requests, eventlet

I need to implement a script to send HTTP requests as quickly as possible. I have tried **eventlet + requests**. The code as following shown, note that I have set the timeout value to **1 second**.

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=False, socket=True)

import requests

params = {
    'token': '???',
    'data': '???'
}

def request_s(session, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return session.request(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        pass  # ignore first
    finally:
        pass

def send():
    pile = eventlet.GreenPile(30)
    s = requests.Session()
    for i in range(100):
        pile.spawn(request_s, s, 'https://api.???.com/', params=params, timeout=1)
    # Fetch response
    for response in pile:
        if response:
            print response.elapsed, response.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send()
```

But I got a strange issue, that is the elapsed time of some requests will exceeds 1 second. The biggest one is about **11 seconds**. why?

In this case, eventlet + requests only 4 ~ 6 times faster than the serial model. Is there any better approach to make this process faster?

Comment: Change the pool size to 10, will get a better performance. But I do not understand why.

Comment: Try to remove session. Maybe it attempts to put 100 requests into one TCP connection, one by one.

Comment: @temoto, the Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance. The requests will share a connection pool instead of a single TCP connection.

Comment: The code seems stateless to me. Have you tried to skip session?